# How to add paytabs library to react js project

Tags: reactjs, paytabs

I try to import `paytabs` to react js project but it doesn't work

```js
var paytabs = require('paytabs')
paytabs.ValidateSecretKey("my email in the dashboard", "my secret Key", function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should try to provide some more info. What doesn't work exactly? Do you receive an error message? Does _anything_ happen at all? ...

Comment: yes the importation of paytabs doesn't work